# How to update the column value in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

In my scenario the column **my_url** can be at first level or inside the **nested column**
how to change the value of the column recursively.the nested column can be a StructType or ArrayType and **my_url**
either it can be at **2nd** level

```
root
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- websites: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- cb_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- domain_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- facebook_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- homepage_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- linkedin_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- my_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- phone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- twitter_url: string (nullable = true)
```

or it can be at **1st level**:

```
root
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- my_url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- facebook_url: string (nullable = true)
```

or like the below

```
root
 |-- _id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- investments: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- investment_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- funding_round_info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- announced_on: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- my_url: string (nullable = true)
```

***it can be at any level.***